# Exception thrown in handler functions

Tags: c++, exception

I am reading following text in applied C++ book.

> Can exceptions be thrown from within our handler functions? The answer
>   is yes, an error can indeed be thrown. The problem is that this
>   exception must be in every exception specification that may be
>   tranversed until the exception is caught. If this is not done, the
>   application will call std::terminate(). For a large system, this
>   amounts to adding an exception specification to every function ,
>   unless you understand the dynamics of your application perfectly. It
>   is also important to cath all exceptions within your destructor;
>   otherwise, std::terminate() will be called as well in this case.

In above text I have following questions and need your help in understanding.

1. What does author mean by "exception must be in every expection specification that may be traversed" ?
2. My understanding is that destructor we cannot use exceptions. What does author mean to catch all exceptions within your destructor.

Request to clarify with simple examples

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, exception specifications are a bad idea, because it produces a lot of refactoring and scale problems (The problems wich the autor talks about) when you modify the specifications. This is the case of [java checked exceptions](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TheProblemWithCheckedExceptions). C++ has no checked exceptions, but the problem with exception specifications are the same, if you want to write an uniform API.

In fact **[exception specifications are deprecated since C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec)**. C++11 uses `noexcept` specifier to ensure that a function not throws any exception. This allows certain compiler optimizations, and of course provides guaranties for the user of the function. If a function doesn't have the `noexcept` specifier, it can throw a exception or not.

Exceptions are, as it name says, *exceptional*. That is, using `try...catch` for flow-control is a bad programming technique. If your program is well designed, when a exception is thrown, means something go very very wrong. That is, a exceptional execution case. And normally that exceptional execution event translates to execution abort. This is why functions not have `try..catch` blocks everywhere where an exception could be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

When an exception is thrown and not caught, the stack unwinds. This means that destructors will be called, everything will be cleaned up nicely. But consider this:

```
foo::~foo()
{
    bar();
}
```

If we reach the destructor of `foo` because of an uncaught exception, and `bar();` happens to throw, the application is immediately terminated, because C++ can not handle more than one exception at once.

This would not have happened if we, e.g. swallowed the exception:

```
foo::~foo()
{
    try { bar(); } catch(...) { /* nom nom */ }
}
```

**Update**:

The first part refers to exception specifications like this:

```
struct foo
{
    void bar() throw();
}
```

Valid syntax for this specification is

```
throw() // does not throw any exception
throw( list of exceptions ) // may throw one of these exceptions
throw(...) // may throw any exception
```

but as rodrigo mentioned, this turned out to be a bad idea, because these specifications led to dynamic checks (during runtime) whether an exception is thrown, significantly slowing down the performance.

In C++11 it is replaced by the `noexcept` keyword:

```
noexcept(true)
noexcept(false)
noexcept // identical to noexcept(true)
```

which is a guarantee that you give to the compiler, not the other way around.

But now finally to your question. When you give `throw` exception specification in some nested chain, and you throw an exception in a deeply nested function, you will have to update the signature of every function along the way. Another very good reason why exception specifications were stupid and should not be used anymore.

Comment: @ nijansen: Thanks for clarification. Can you please clarify first question

Answer (score 0):

1. Exceptions specifications turned out to be a bad idea, and I think that they are deprecated in the latest revision of the language, so I'd just ignore it.
2. Generally speaking, destructors must not throw any exception. Because they are called during the stack unwinding that happens when an exception is thrown/catch. If an exception is thrown while the stack is unwinding, the program will abort. The easy/safe solution is to wrap the destructor body with a `try {...} catch (..} {}` block.

Comment: Never use or recommend anyone else to have catch-all clause that does not re-throw or abort the application.

Comment: @VladLazarenko IMO, this has nothing to do with recommending - it's the OP asking what the author means by a quote, and "catch all exceptions" is pretty unambiguous in this case

Comment: @mel-: No, catch all exceptions means catch all exceptions. Good C++ developers would never use catch-all clause like that. Just for the sake of example, read [this](http://udrepper.livejournal.com/21541.html).

Comment: @VladLazarenko: I'm not recommending the catch-all clause, but that's what seems to be suggested in the OP quote, and that's what's being asked.

Comment: @rodrigo: I think what was suggested is to catch every exception that might arise in destructor code, explicitly. And otherwise use `no except` specified and abort the program if something unknown is thrown. But not using catch-all.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Actually saying that aborting the program is _always_ better than ignore an unknown exception is a bit... too general. There are a lot of applications out there that must not (or cannot) abort so easily. Sometimes it is better to note that something is going wrong, notify the user/supervisor, and (try to) go on.

Comment: @rodrigo: Sometimes it is. But the rule of thumb is to not catch anything that you do not how to handle. For example, you better do not handle foreign or ABI exceptions, etc.